# How do I save JWT response header using fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, fetch

I'm using React and using fetch to send a request to the server:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8001/api/login", {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: 'username=' + this.state.username + '&password=' + this.state.password
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    console.log(data.headers.toString())
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```

[This is chrome inspect, it shows that I get JWT token from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHmdX.png)
My question is how do I access it in my code? I actually need to save it to a variable, there's really no way to do

```
data.headers.jwt
```

I'm sorry if this makes no sense, I can clarify if you need.

Comment: I searched some more and I think it might have something to do with this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816592/8608962

Comment: yes, server needs to send appropriate `access-control-expose-headers` to expose them. Note: where you say `Request succeeded with JSON response` that's **not** a JSON response, it's a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object

Comment: I added
_header('access-control-expose-headers');_ to the beginning of the server file. How would I access the headers in ReactJS?

Comment: well, you need to **specify** which headers to expose - then, the `jwt` header is accessed using `data.headers.get('jwt')`

Comment: to be honest, unless there's a really good reason not to, I'd put the `jwt` in the response body, not a response header - but, as your code as posted doesn't ever access the response body, it's hard to say if adding the jwt to the response body is correct for your case or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code you need. As a bonus, I have added on some code to show you how to use the response data.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8001/api/login", {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: 'username=' + this.state.username + '&password=' + this.state.password
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('My JWT:', response.headers.get('jwt'));
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    // Do something with JSON data.
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```