# Missing headers in Fetch response

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I need to make a `CORS post request`. I need to use `fetch` because `axios`'s `response` is already processed to json.

But in `fetch` response, the `headers` is empty. But I don't think this is the server problem since `axios` response headers have the values that I want.

Any trick?

```
    fetch('http://localhost:9876/test/sample-download', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {},
        body: {}
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

    axios.post('http://localhost:9876/test/sample-download', {}, {})
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Have you tried to construct a request object using `var myRequest = new Request(url, opts)` and then passing it to `fetch(myRequest)`? What does `console.log(response.headers)` show then?

Comment: @Alexander I just tried. no luck . `let myReq = new Request('http://localhost:9876/test/sample-download', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {},
            body: JSON.stringify({}),
            cache: 'no-cache'
        });
        fetch(myReq)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: I suspect it's because the Headers class instance that fetch returns is an iterable, as opposed to a plain object like axios returns. An iterable's data isn't viewable from the console, you have to iterate it and console.log each element, like `response.headers.forEach(console.log)`. Try that maybe?

Comment: @ccnokes Thanks. that solved my issue. If you could post that as an answer, I can mark it.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) class instance that fetch returns is an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), as opposed to a plain object like axios returns. Some iterable's data, such as Headers or URLSearchParams, aren't viewable from the console, you have to iterate it and console.log each element, like:

```
fetch('http://localhost:9876/test/sample-download', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {},
    body: {}
})
.then(response => {
  // Inspect the headers in the response
  response.headers.forEach(console.log);
  // OR you can do this
  for(let entry of response.headers.entries()) {
    console.log(entry);
  }
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Hopefully Chrome changes the display of Headers in dev tools to display like Map or Set does. Those types give helpful previews of the entries. They also have an `[[Entries]]` property, so maybe that's the difference.

Comment: This and the answer from @AndyTheEntity helped immensely! Thank you!

Comment: the .forEach(console.log) part spams my console with duplicates of the same headers

Answer (score 99):

Headers are limited for CORS requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816592/2047472

(Use `access-control-expose-headers` to allow exposing headers to requests from a different origin.)

Comment: This is the real answer.

Comment: where do we set this? client side/server side? where?

Comment: @Prime server-side

Answer (score 42):

Although the correct answer is the one from @AndyTheEntity for me is a little bit incomplete.

CORS requests have limitations and show only a subset of headers:

- `Cache-Control`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type`
- `Expires`
- `Last-Modified`
- `Pragma`

In order to show more headers on the response, the **server** has to add a header to allow more extra headers.

For example, after a POST request if a new resource is created you should return a 201 CREATED response and add a `Location` header.
If you need to accept CORS also you need to add the next headers (on the **server** response):

```
Location: $url-of-created-resource
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
```

With this you will see on the client the header `Location`.

If you need to send an specific header (like a `SESSION_ID`), then you need to add the next header in the **request**:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: SESSION_ID
SESSION_ID: $current_session_id
```

I hope this cover all needs to handle request/response using CORS.

Comment: also `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *` to expose all headers or `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Header1, Header2` to expose multiple. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Answer (score 16):

To get a specific header property you can use the following:

```
response.headers.get(yourProperty)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), for instance, `Object.fromEntries(response.headers)` or `Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries())`. This method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.

```js
fetch("https://www.google.com").then(response => console.log(Object.fromEntries(response.headers)))
//-> Promise <pending>

// console.log output:
{
    "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
    "bfcache-opt-in": "unload",
    "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
    "content-encoding": "br",
    "content-length": "41556",
    "content-security-policy": "upgrade-insecure-requests",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Wed, 04 Aug 2021 08:09:30 GMT",
    "expires": "-1",
    "server": "gws",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x-xss-protection": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this one from another answer here spams my console with duplicates of the .headers content:

`response.headers.forEach(console.log)`

But this one works, it creates a map:

`console.log(...response.headers)`

or for a better readable console output check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70821115/4394435