# Response.header in console shows blank, but in the network tab there are headers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to programmatically access the headers of a response.

PS: Using Chrome.
If I add a breakpoint and inspect the response object, it looks like it has no headers.

If I try print of the headers, both of these log statements show `{}`:

```
    const response = await fetch(request);
    console.log('headers stringify:', response.headers);
    console.log('headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
```

However in the Chrome dev tools `Network` tab it shows the response had headers. How does one access the headers of a response object?

Comment: What headers are you seeing in the Network tab? And what do you see when you use [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get) to access one of them? (E.g., if one of the headers is `Example`, what do you get for `console.log(response.headers.get("Example"));`?)

Comment: I think this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413050/missing-headers-in-fetch-response

In short: you don't see any headers because you are not printing them properply.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alittleSalty for the link which explains the headers are an iterable, and can be seen with:

```
response.headers.forEach((value, key) => console.log("header:", key, 'value:', value));
```

Comment: If the answer aLittleSalty linked answers this question (which makes sense), don't post that as an answer, close the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: Fair enough, although this answer does have value in that it shows how to get the key/value pairs, which to me are provided in reverse order to whats expected.

Comment: If there aren't answers there showing it, you can post it on the other question. The point is to put the answers to the issue in one place. :-)

Comment: (You can also do `console.log(...response.headers);` Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68647698/157247).)

Comment: Okay thank you! I have voted to close this, and marked it as duplicate.