# shopify-app-bridge AuthenticatedFetch not returning response headers for reauthorization

Tags: node.js, shopify-app, shopify-app-bridge

I am building an embedded app in Shopify using the shopify-app-react template.

In there is an authenticatedFetch hook that looks like below (logging added by me)

```
export function useAuthenticatedFetch() {
  const app = useAppBridge();
  const fetchFunction = authenticatedFetch(app);

  return async (uri, options) => {
    console.log("opts", uri, options);
    const response = await fetchFunction(uri, options);
    console.log("response", response);
    checkHeadersForReauthorization(response.headers, app);
    return response;
  };
}

function checkHeadersForReauthorization(headers, app) {
  console.log("headers", headers);
  if (headers.get("X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize") === "1") {
    const authUrlHeader =
      headers.get("X-Shopify-API-Request-Failure-Reauthorize-Url") ||
      `/api/auth`;

    console.log("url", authUrlHeader);

    const redirect = Redirect.create(app);
    redirect.dispatch(
      Redirect.Action.REMOTE,
      authUrlHeader.startsWith("/")
        ? `https://${window.location.host}${authUrlHeader}`
        : authUrlHeader
    );
  }
}
```

When using this fetch hook to make a request, the request looks something like below

[image]

However the logging ends up looking something like this

[image]

It looks like the fetch response in code is not matching the fetch response headers in the browser, and thus I can't get a redirect for reauthorization. Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a cors issue, as the app frontend is hosted on s3 and the backend via api gateway. The below answer helped me understand it a little more and the solution was to add Access-Control-Expose-Headers for the 2 shopify headers to api gateway.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56959114/1422679