# How to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to POST /login endpoint?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security

My goal is to get the `X-Auth-Token` header using JavaScript.

```
let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", username);
formData.append("password", password);

fetch("/login, {
  method: "POST",
  redirect: "manual",
  body: formData,
})
.then(response => console.log(response.headers));
```

My expected result is: The `response.headers` contains `X-Auth-Token` key and value.

My actual result is: The `response.headers` is empty. I checked the browser's inspect tool `Ctrl+Shift+I` > Network > login and the response headers has `X-Auth-Token` header.

What I've tried

1. Create bean corsConfigurationSource inside `public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurer`

```
@Bean CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource {
  CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
  configuration.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("X-Auth-Token"));
  
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
  return source;
}
```

I use Postman and the browser's inspect tool to see the response headers but it does not contain the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. The `response.headers` is still empty.

## Edit

I added bean with `@EnableWebSecurity` and Override `configure(HttpSecurity http)`.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/chat").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  // TODO: vulnerability test.
  // require:
  // 1. Add a bean with @EnableWebSecurity
  // 2. Override configure(HttpSecurity http) http.cors()
  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));

    config.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("X-Auth-Token"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return source;
  }
}
```

Then, I sent the request to POST /login from `Origin: http://localhost:3000` endpoint with body of FormData. The problem persists and I still can't get the `X-Auth-Token` header's value although the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header and the `X-Auth-Token` header are present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you disable cors in WebSecurityConfig class?
You have configure method in your class? ;If I don't remember wrong, there is a cors filter in spring security. Maybe implementing cors filter will help you.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Hi, I added the CORS with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, but I still can't get the `X-Auth-Token` header.

Comment: Are you sure fetch that returns promise response can get the other headers like Content-type and length? If not then you need to configure fetch function to get headers

Comment: Which framework are you using in front-end?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I am not sure how to answer your question. But, from the `console.log` the `response.headers` is empty. I use React JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779681/headers-not-showing-in-fetch-response

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I've tried it with `response.headers.get("x-auth-token")` it returns `null`.