# Returning response header OnAuthenticationFailed

Tags: javascript, c#, api, asp.net-core, http-headers

I am trying to return an altered header if the token a user sends up is expired so that I can resend up my refresh token if it is expired.

I am using .NET Core 2.2 with "In-Process" hosting incase that matters.

Here is my `ConfigureServices` method from my `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "bearer";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "bearer";
}).AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["serverSigningPassword"])),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.Zero //the default for this setting is 5 minutes
    };
    options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
            }
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

And then when I try to fetch on an "authorize" endpoint from javascript with the following.

```js
async function fetchWithCredentials(url, options) {    
    options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jwtToken;
    var response = await fetch(url, options);
    if (response.ok) { //all is good, return the response
        return response;
    }

    console.log(response.headers) //nothing in this array

    // it will never do this "if" statement because there are no headers
    if (response.status === 401 && response.headers.has('Token-Expired')) {
        // refresh the token
        return await fetchWithCredentials(url, options); //repeat the original request
    } else { //status is not 401 and/or there's no Token-Expired header
        return response; 
    }
}
```

This image is from hovering over the header. It certainly hits my breakpoint (for the `context.Response.Headers.Add()` and I can see the count = 1 (which is the "Token-Expired" when I examine it).

[image]

Finally, here is a screenshot from Postman after a failed request so the response is sending, but not being received in my JS.
[image]

Any ideas as to why my header is not sticking to my response in the javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a restriction to access response headers when you are using Fetch API over CORS. Due to this restriction, you can access only following standard headers:

- `Cache-Control`
- `Content-Language`
- `Content-Type`
- `Expires`
- `Last-Modified`
- `Pragma`

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816592/5751404

So one way to access your custom header in client is to add the header `access-control-expose-headers` to response, with the comma-separated headers:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .WithExposedHeaders("Token-Expired"); ;
}));
```

In `Configure`:

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

So that you can access the custom header from client using Fetch API over CORS .

Comment: Hi @NanYu, I only want that response to be returned when the authentication fails though. Not for every request

Comment: @thalacker , you are only add Token-Expired as header value in `OnAuthenticationFailed ` event , so that meets your requirement .

Answer (score 1):

Here I describe for both - 
1. Token expire and get refresh token
2. Only for unauthorized request.

```
async function fetchWithCredentials(url, options) {    
    options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + jwtToken;
    var response = await fetch(url, options);//this is a function for get a response. I didn't explain it here. Hope you understand. 
    if (response.ok) {
        return response;
    }

    let flag:boolean=false; //set flag for executing one if statement at a time.

if (response.status == 401 && response.headers.has('Token-Expired')) {
        // refresh the token
        flag=true;  //set flag true.
        //write something as per your requirement.
    } 

if (response.status == 401 && flag==false) {
        **// Only for unauthorized request. You can use this for your problem.**
        //write something as per your requirement.
    } 
}
```

And most important thing is, You have to use below code in startup.cs.

```
services.AddCors(context => context.AddPolicy("CustomPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .WithExposedHeaders("Token-Expired"); ;
}));
```

In Configure:

```
app.UseCors("CustomPolicy");
```

and use below code as it is.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "bearer";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "bearer";
}).AddJwtBearer("bearer", options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["serverSigningPassword"])),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.Zero //the default for this setting is 5 minutes
    };
    options.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
            }
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Now, you'll get response on client side.
Hope you'll find your solution. Please let me know for any doubt.