# Read headers from CORS response return empty object

Tags: javascript, cors, http-headers

When I do a fetch with javascript in the browser (with basic auth) I get a response like in the screenshot.
This is fine, but why does `console.log(response.headers)` returns an empty object?

I added the `acces-control-expose-headers` because it is a cors request and I would like to have the date.

The goal is to cache the response (Cache API) and use the date to get the age of the cache.
But also the cache version doesn't return headers. (but with the dev tools in chrome I can see that all the headers are in the cache)

Here is part of the code:

```js
    const cache = await caches.open('data');
    let response = await cache.match(url)
    if (!response) {
      response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: new Headers({
          "Authorization": 'Basic 1234fake567=='
        })
      });
      if (!response.ok) return dispatch(setError(response.status.toString()));
      console.log(response.headers)  // => {}
      await cache.put(url, response)
      response = await cache.match(url)
    }
    console.log(response.headers) // => {}
    const apiData: ApiData = await response.json();
```

[image: request/response details]

Comment: what's your script? could you post a bit of it?

Comment: Try `response.headers.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value));` You can also get an individual header using `response.headers.get('...')`

Comment: Are you awaiting your fetch properly? Need to see code.

Comment: I added some code

Comment: Could it be because of the limitation in CORS mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344819/reading-response-headers-with-fetch-api)?

Comment: I should then get the standard headers and the Date that I added with acces-control-expose-headers?

Comment: I'm marking this as dupe: [Reading response headers with Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344819/reading-response-headers-with-fetch-api)

Comment: That question is about a header that is not added. This question is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344819/reading-response-headers-with-fetch-api), you cannot use `console.log(response.headers)` to debug print the headers. Instead try this:

```
    const cache = await caches.open('data');
    let response = await cache.match(url)
    if (!response) {
      response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: new Headers({
          "Authorization": 'Basic 1234fake567=='
        })
      });
      if (!response.ok) return dispatch(setError(response.status.toString()));
      

      // This is new
      for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
         console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]);
      }

      await cache.put(url, response)
      response = await cache.match(url)
    }
    console.log(response.headers) // => {}
    const apiData: ApiData = await response.json();
```

Comment: Damn, this just works: `response.headers.get('Date')`. I did try that, but I geus before adding that cors header and didn't try again. Thanks!

Comment: Just realized, that this is what Chris G mentions in the comments

Comment: yes, I couldn't believe that would work :-) I read that SO post, but that first answer is only part of the solution. The second answer was now my solution.

Comment: @roeland honestly it's pretty obscure, that `result.headers` prints as `{}` giving the false impression, that it works

Comment: If you find an existing question, please don't post an answer. Mark it as duplicate instead.