# filterSerializedResponseHeaders replacement for client

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am fetching the data in my `+page.ts` file like this:

```js
import type { UserOverview } from '$lib/types/user';
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';

export const load = (async ({ fetch}) => {
    let entryCount: number;
    const users: UserOverview[] = await fetch("<Url>", {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    })
        .then((r) => {
            entryCount = parseInt(r.headers.get('X-Total-Count') as string);
            return r.json();
        });
    return {
        users,
        entryCount
    };
}) satisfies PageLoad;
```

so that i can access the entryCount in my `+page.svelte`.
On SSR the `X-Total-Count` wasn't present, so I added this code to my `hooks.server.ts` file.

```js
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    return resolve(event, {
        filterSerializedResponseHeaders: (name) => name.startsWith('x')
    });
}) satisfies Handle;
```

And it works now on SSR.

However on CSR, the header `X-Total-Count` is not present in the load function.

As the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks) state `filterSerializedResponseHeaders` only exists as a server hook.

The API response (dev-tools) does include the header, but it does not show up in the load function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to to with svelte or sveltekit, instead it was a problem with cors. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291644/19821011) solved it.